# Autocomplete in excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to make a cell with autocomplete of other sheet specific column values?
I am new in VBA, need some guidelines where to look at?
"Data Validation" does a lot, but there I have a huge dropdown list, which is not searchable.

Comment: Does my answer fit to your requirements or you need another approach?

Answer (score 0):

You may not need VBA to do such a task. Maybe you should check a possible solution in this [link](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/autocomplete-validation.htm)

**Solution (from link above):**

1. Go to Tools -> Options -> Edit and check Enable AutoComplete for cell values (extra: in Excel 2013 go to File -> Options -> Formulas -> Working With Formulas -> Check "Formula AutoComplete")
2. Move your list of items is in the range immediately above the Validation cell.
3. Hide the rows above your Validation cell.

When you start type below the list Excel will suggest you possible completions.

HTH ;)